# Can you power the ESP8266E-12 with any of the 3.3V pins?

Tags: esp8266, power, nodemcu, pins

If I want to operate the NodeMCU on the 3.3V input with 2.5V to 3.6V; can I use any of the 3.3V pins to do so?

[image]

Comment: The 3.3V pins have this name for a reason. You need to provide 3.3V. 2.5V is a bit too low

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the nodeMCU board all the 3.3v pins have continuity. That means they all do the same thing. And yes, you can apply ~3.3v to them. I have trouble with voltages under ~2.8 though, 2.5v is likely not going to work.

Use a buck+boost to keep it 3.3v if needed. For cheap dc/dc converters, I strongly prefer ones with XL semi chips; clean enough to please the ESPs.